# when resizing my browser my website resize with it

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, web

I wrote a [website](http://www.eurobytes.nl/) but I have a bug in it, when I resize my browser my website resizes with it.  I have noticed this in Firefox (10.0.2), Chrome (16.0.912.77) and opera (11.60).  I tested some other websites [omgubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/) [webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/) and when I resize Firefox it still looks good (it doesn't resize with the web-browser).  I would love to post images but I need 10 reputation for that.

Comment: i want to be able to go to my website and when resizing my web browser that it wont resize with it like omgubuntu and webupd8

Comment: I gave you point for the question, there you know how 10 reputation you may post pictures. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS, apply a width (such as 1000px) to your `<body>` and add `margin: 0 auto;` to centre the content. You'll have to bring the width of your navigation links down and re-position the ads, but this will stop your site from 'resizing' with your browser.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest using a good CSS Framework. Two good options are:

http://960.gs/
http://blueprintcss.org/

They provide you a fixed width layout as well as an easy way to divide the column into grids.